# Is it possible to output embedded mixin rules without passing them as a mixin parameter?

Tags: less

```
.mixin(@param) {
  @{param} & {
    @thoseRules(); // color: blue
  }
}

button {
  display: block;

  .mixin('param') {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Is something like the above possible in LESS without passing the property block as a parameter of the mixin?

Comment: Trying to not pass the `color: blue` rule as a parameter of the mixin call, hoping that some keyword like SASS `@content` or Stylus `{block}` has those available.

Comment: Oh, could you show me a sample of SASS or Stylus and I can see if it can be ported to Less? Sorry, I don't know the other two.

Comment: Surely! This is an example of `{block}` from the Stylus docs http://stylus-lang.com/docs/mixins.html#block-mixins. It's a special keyword to access the properties without having to pass them to the mixin directly.

This would be the same in SASS with the `@content` keyword. http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixin-content

Comment: As far as I know, Less doesn't have an exact equivalent (of either the Stylus or the SASS version). At best you could do [this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.mixin(%40param%2C%20%40thoseRules)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.%40%7Bparam%7D%20%26%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40thoseRules()%3B%20%2F%2F%20color%3A%20blue%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnbutton%20%7B%5Cn%20%20display%3A%20block%3B%5Cn%5Cn%20%20.mixin(param%2C%20%40button)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%40button%3A%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20color%3A%20blue%3B%5Cn%7D%3B%22%7D). We are just assigning property block to a variable and passing it instead of the block itself.

Comment: I was afraid that's the case, thanks for the help either way!

Comment: @Harry, "At best you could do this" - not quite, the most equivalent code would be [this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.mixin(%40param%2C%20%40rules)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.%40%7Bparam%7D%20%26%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40rules()%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnbutton%20%7B%5Cn%20%20display%3A%20block%3B%5Cn%5Cn%20%20.mixin(param%2C%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20color%3A%20blue%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D)%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: But that's exactly what OP wanted to avoid (passing property block in mixin call) which is why I said the only alternate to it is - setting it to a variable and passing the variable :)

Comment: @Harry Ah, then probably I did not understand the question properly. What is the point in wanting to pass something to something and in the same time to refuse to actually explicitly write you *do* pass it? :) Is it just about syntactic sugar?

Comment: Possibly @seven-phases-max. It just seems like OP did not want to pass it explicitly in the mixin call as a param. In SASS, they are using same name (with include and content) whereas in Stylus they are just adding a + before what otherwise seems like a mixin block.

Comment: Then [this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.mixin(%40param)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.%40%7Bparam%7D%20%26%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40content()%3B%20%2F%2F%20color%3A%20blue%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnbutton%20%7B%5Cn%20%20display%3A%20block%3B%5Cn%5Cn%20%20.mixin(param)%3B%20%40content%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20color%3A%20blue%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%22%7D) (half-joking of course) variant will look closer (Now it literally passes something w/o passing it explicitly).